# Is there a way to compare or do a delta of VS 2010 Code Analysis, Metrics and Code Coverage results?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-analysis, code-metrics

I have started to work with the Code Measurement and Analysis features of VS2010; i.e. the code analysis, code metrics and code coverage. I have gone through the details about how to run these tools (using VS and automate via the command line) and have also looked at the results.

I was wondering if there is way to compare the results to better understand the "progress", meaning how the quality of code has been improving on an ongoing basis? For example, I would like to compare the code metrics statistics (xml results file) from a previous build and compare it with the current build.

Is there a tool available for this that I am not aware of? Right now we are thinking about storing results in excel and do comparisons and charting on it as we progress.

Appreciate if anyone has any thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only dedicated comparison tool of which I am aware is one that I created a few years ago, which available at http://finlogikfxcopstats.codeplex.com/.  I am no longer responsible for its maintenance, and I'm not sure if it's been updated for FxCop 10.0.  However, its source code is available, so you can tweak it if you need to...

[TFS also offers some results tracking](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2008/01/02/reporting-code-analysis-defect-counts.aspx) from which historical reports can be generated.  However, I find its approach pretty useless since it means that you need to keep your backlog "active", which means that you can't fail builds based on new problems.

Comment: Thanks Nicole. I will check out your code. I have also not looked at results tracking yet and will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer I am a developer of the tool quoted*: With the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/), you can write a [Code Query over LINQ (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) to match evolution through any code metrics. For example you could start with the query:

```
from t in JustMyCode.Types
where t.IsPresentInBothBuilds() &&
      t.CodeWasChanged()
let tOld = t.OlderVersion()

let newLoC = t.NbLinesOfCode  
let oldLoC = tOld.NbLinesOfCode
let newCC = t.CyclomaticComplexity
let oldCC = tOld.CyclomaticComplexity
let newCov = t.PercentageCoverage
let oldCov = tOld.PercentageCoverage
where newLoC > oldLoC || newCC > oldCC || newCov < oldCov
select new { t, newLoC, oldLoC, newCC, oldCC, newCov, oldCov }
```

...and get an instant result in Visual Studio. Such rule is integrable into your [CI TFS build process](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_TFS.aspx) and can also be shown in a [HTML+javascript report](http://www.ndepend.com/SampleReports.aspx).

[image: Code metric evolution match]

Comment: You certainly do not try to be sneaky about your affiliation with NDepend, and you post many very useful answers in your area of knowledge. However, posts like this just feel a bit too sales-like for this site. I'm not flagging it as spam or anything, but just a friendly reminder to be careful when your answers start using marketing-speak.

Comment: Andrew, I rephrased the post to both discard any doubt about my affiliation with NDepend, and inform more in-depth shanks. Since shanks wrote: Is there a tool available for this that I am not aware of? and NDepend does **exactly** and in a clean way what he's asking for, hopefully my answer is relevant.

Comment: That's all well and good. But when a large number of your posts read like the marketing section of your website, there will be a problem. Just FYI. Like I said, you also do some good support posts, so I'm inclined to just give you a friendly heads-up :)